# Python строка с Unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, unicode

есть строка '4\xa0317.06' что является -> 4 317.06

как преобразовать эту строку в float()

Comment: уже сделал путем 
.replace('\xa0', '')

Comment: напишите кто-то ответ этот, чтобы я закрыл вопрос, а то не знаю как иначе(

Comment: Вообще-то `\xa0` - это обычный неразрывный пробел, а ни разу не юникод.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\xa0` - код неразрывного пробела (он не позволяет переносить слова в этом месте), поэтому в вашем случае достаточно сделать так:

```
string = '4\xa0317.06'
number = float(string.replace('\xa0', ''))
```